# Loop data frame columns in glm function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to do some basic univariate regression analysis in a data frame. Basically I have 20 columns with different types of data, and I want to do the following:

```
glm_test <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
summary(glm_test)
```

And then `x` should obviously be each column of the data frame.
I have tried for loops with just the names of the columns, or using `df[[i]]`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

So yeah, is this even possible in a simple way, or is it more tricky than it looks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  tmp=as.formula(paste0("y~",colnames(df)[i]))
  glm_test <- glm(tmp, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df)
  summary(glm_test)
}
```